# My binary conversion app only goes up to 5 binary digits, how do I write the code to make it limitless without having to write all the repetitive code

Tags: python, binary, repeat

Is there any way I can make the limitation to the whole number you can convert to binary endless without having to write endless repetitive code for each stage of the whole number to binary conversion.

```
 #this is my first attempt at creating a integer to binary converter
    #currently only works with 5 digit binary output

    integer = int(input('Please input a whole number you would like converted in to binary '))
    
    remainder_1 = (integer) % 2
    division_1 = (integer) // 2
    #print(remainder_1)
    #print(f"d1 {division_1}")
    
    remainder_2 = (division_1 % 2)
    division_2 = (division_1 // 2)
    if division_2 == 0 and remainder_2 == 0:
        remainder_2 = ('')
    #print(remainder_2)
    #print(f"d2 {division_2}")
    
    remainder_3 = (division_2 % 2)
    division_3 = (division_2 // 2)
    if division_3 == 0 and remainder_3 ==0:
        remainder_3 = ('')
    #print(remainder_3)
    #print(f"d3 {division_3}")
    
    remainder_4 = (division_3 % 2)
    division_4 = (division_3 // 2)
    if division_4 == 0 and remainder_4 ==0:
        remainder_4 = ('')
    #print(remainder_4)
    #print(f"d4 {division_4}")
    
    remainder_5 = (division_4 % 2)
    division_5 = (division_4 // 2)
    if division_5 == 0 and remainder_5 ==0:
        remainder_5 = ('')
    #print(remainder_5)
    #print(f"d5 {division_5}")
    
    remainder_6 = (division_5 % 2)
    division_6 = (division_5 // 2)
    if division_6 == 0 and remainder_6 ==0:
        remainder_6 = ('')
    #print(remainder_6)
    #print(f"d6 {division_6}")
    
    
    
    Binary = (f'{remainder_6}{remainder_5}{remainder_4}{remainder_3}{remainder_2}{remainder_1}')
    print (Binary)
```

also when printing the binary result is there a way to repeat printing of remainders in order of most significant number to least significant number without having to write it all out as I did above up until remainder 6, Of course depending on how large the whole number input is initially.

Comment: Learning about the basics of Python will help you.

Comment: Why  not to use `bin` function?

Comment: instead of using repeated code, we can use a while loop, that can handle whatever input is coming.

Comment: This is me in the process of learning basics of python, and bin function would just give me the answer, It's the method I wanted. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
integer = int(input('Please input a whole number you would like converted in to binary '))
binary = ""

# while integer is greater than zero.
while integer > 0:
    # get the remainder of integer divided by 2.
    remainder = str(integer % 2)
    # concat the remainder as prefix to the binary string
    binary = remainder + binary
    # integer division by 2 on the integer
    integer = integer // 2

print(binary)
```

Output

```
Please input a whole number you would like converted in to binary  100
1100100
```

Comment: Ok so to get the binary read in the right order that's why you did remainder+ binary instead of binary + remainder

Comment: any you set binary to string as well as the remainder so it wouldn't be added up as integers but just neatly placed side by side, awesome thank you

Comment: very clear answer!